# how to build a 3d donut chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I wonder if it's possible to build a 3d donut chart in html.
I have found a interesting link [here](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-donut-chart/) but infortunatly i need to add links (or javascript event) when clicking to launch a ajax request.

Have you ever done such a thing ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You either download a charting library that does this for you, or you spend the next two months writing it from scratch, and that is if you know what you're doing ?

Comment: you need two months for that ? ;))

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria' - Probably not, but creating the 3D stuff in a canvas isn't done in an hour.

Comment: I'm afraid i haven't 2 mounths so i gonna still searching such library

Comment: the 3d stuff is very simple if you know the Math behind it .. look below this was written in 2 hours including time for the mathematics ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example I've just made:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/baQCD/3/embedded/result/

The key point (pun intended) is to add a url key for each row (object) in the data array, and use it in the 'click' event handler:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function(e) {
            location.href = e.point.url;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
},
```

In your case instead of opening a new url, you could do your ajax request or do anything else. In my example I've shown how to manipulate the data and title.

```
click: function(e) {
    if (this.name == "Randomize!") {
        sliceK = getRandomInt(0,chart.series[0].data.length-1);
        chart.options.series[0].data[sliceK].y = getRandomInt(1,30);
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart.options);
    } else if (this.name == "Link") {
        location.href = this.url;
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        chart.setTitle(null,{text:this.name + " clicked"});
    }
}
```

You can immediately see, 2 features I very like in Highcharts, the ability to print or download the chart, and the ability to disable part of the data (removing it from the chart) by clicking on the legend.

---

This is based on the code shown in:

http://birdchan.com/home/2012/09/07/highcharts-pie-charts-can-have-url-links/
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie-donut/

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple 3d Axonometric class i wrote for testing, its very simple it puts the canvas transformation into a plane of zy or zx or yx... it uses canvas setTransform
you first have to call the axionometric class with phi and theta the angles of view
get_bd is a function where you can enter x,y,z coordinates and the method returns an object with b and d value... b is the x of the screen and d is the y of the screen.

i have appended and example, you just have to put a canvas tag in the html with id canvasView

```
//3d Maths - Axonometric -- Artner Thorsten -- Austria -- Wiener Neustadt

var context=document.getElementById("canvasView").getContext("2d");

function Axonometric (phi,theta)
    {
    var cosPHI=Math.cos(phi);
    var sinPHI=Math.sin(phi);
    var cosTHETA=Math.cos(theta);
    var sinTHETA=Math.sin(theta);

    this.cosPHI=cosPHI;
    this.sinPHI=sinPHI;
    this.cosTHETA=cosTHETA;
    this.sinTHETA=sinTHETA;

    this.phi=phi;
    this.theta=theta;
    }

Axonometric.prototype.get_bd=function (x,y,z)
    {
    var b=y*this.cosPHI-x*this.sinPHI-500;
    var d=x*this.cosPHI*this.cosTHETA+y*this.sinPHI*this.cosTHETA-z*this.sinTHETA+500;
    return {b:b,d:d};
    }

Axonometric.prototype.plane_zy=function (x)
    {
    context.setTransform (0,this.sinTHETA,-this.cosPHI,this.sinPHI*this.cosTHETA,500+x*this.sinPHI,500+x*this.cosPHI*this.cosTHETA);
    }

Axonometric.prototype.plane_zx=function (y)
    {
    context.setTransform (this.sinPHI,this.cosPHI*this.cosTHETA,0,this.sinTHETA,500+y*-this.cosPHI,500+y*this.sinPHI*this.cosTHETA);
    }

Axonometric.prototype.plane_yx=function (z)
    {
    context.setTransform (this.sinPHI,this.cosPHI*this.cosTHETA,-this.cosPHI,this.sinPHI*this.cosTHETA,500,500-z*this.sinTHETA);
    }

Axonometric.prototype.draw_axis=function (length)
    {
    var O=this.get_bd (0,0,0);
    var X=this.get_bd (length,0,0);
    var Y=this.get_bd (0,length,0);
    var Z=this.get_bd (0,0,length);
    context.save;
    context.beginPath ();
    context.textAlign="top";
    context.fillText ("X",-X.b,X.d);
    context.moveTo (-O.b,O.d);
    context.lineTo (-X.b,X.d);
    context.strokeStyle="red";
    context.stroke ();
    context.beginPath ();
    context.fillText ("Y",-Y.b,Y.d);
    context.moveTo (-O.b,O.d);
    context.lineTo (-Y.b,Y.d);
    context.strokeStyle="green";
    context.stroke ();
    context.beginPath ();
    context.fillText ("Z",-Z.b,Z.d);
    context.moveTo (-O.b,O.d);
    context.lineTo (-Z.b,Z.d);
    context.strokeStyle="blue";
    context.stroke ();
    context.restore ();
    }

// example
var Viewer=new Axonometric (Math.PI/4, Math.PI/8);
Viewer.draw_axis (400);

Viewer.plane_yx (0);
context.beginPath ();
context.fillStyle="red";
context.fillRect (0,0,200,200);

Viewer.plane_zx (0);
context.beginPath ();
context.fillStyle="lightgrey";
context.fillRect (0,0,200,-200);

Viewer.plane_zy (0);
context.beginPath ();
context.arc (-100,100,100,0,2*Math.PI);
context.fillStyle="black";
context.fill();
```

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not enough familiar in web development to understand your code in ons shoot but i'm gonna take time to stydy it. Tanks for this proposition

Answer (score 1):

Using an existing library is an easy solution. If I'm understanding your question properly, you would like users to be able to click on a slice to open a new URL.

This can be achieved in ZingChart by setting up a "pie3d" type, and then including "url" and "target" in the series.

Here's how I did it:

```
    {
    "graphset":[
        {
            "type":"pie3d",
            "plot":{
                "slice":45
            },
            "plotarea":{
                "margin-top":"35px"
            },
            "series":[
                {
                    "text":"Apples",
                    "values":[5],
                    "url":"http://www.google.com",
                    "target":"_blank"
                },
                {
                    "text":"Oranges",
                    "values":[8]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Bananas",
                    "values":[22]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Grapes",
                    "values":[16]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Cherries",
                    "values":[12]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Merrily's answer, you can also use [ZingChart's API](http://zingchart.com/docs/api/api-events/) to track chart interaction and call any functions you like.

```
var ZCwindow;
function openWindow() {
ZCwindow = window.open("http://zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/pie/", "ZingChart Pie Charts");
}    

zingchart.node_click = function(e){
    if(e.value == 5) openWindow();
};
```

You can view a live demo [here](http://www.zingchart.com/playground/run/5384cfa954313).

*I am part of the ZingChart team. You can reach out to us for assistance via support@zingchart.com*

Comment: Please make it clear that you are ZingCharts in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the past few months I have been working with Google Visualization charts, and I think it may be exactly what you're looking for. [**Here**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut) is the link to the documentation.

This will give you a donut chart (though I am not sure if you can make it 3-D or not, I believe you can) and you can add event handlers for when the user clicks on a slice. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I highly recommend trying the charts, I have found them to be extraordinarily useful. Good luck!

EDIT: My apologies, after re-reading the section on donut charts it appears the new API does not yet support 3-D donut charts. Does it absolutely have to be three-dimensional? If not this is still an excellent choice.

Comment: Thxs derstrom8 i've also see that great library but unfortunately it's really need to have a 3d effects (special thx to my wedesigner :))

Comment: Okay, well that's good to know. I am hoping Google will add that option in soon. The Visualization API is still very new, so they're still making improvements.

I wish you the very best of luck, I hope you can figure it out!

Comment: Another option would be to put invisible divs over the pie slices of the chart you linked to in your original post. You can then make the divs clickable. Would that work?

Comment: I think it should be my backup solution. Thanks derstrom8  for this idea

Answer (score 0):

It's not 3D, but you should have a look at [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/#doughnutChart)